# Is my cgroup overloaded?

Tags: cgroups, cpu-usage

Suppose I limited the cores a set of processes is permitted to use with cgroup/cpuset option.

I need to know if I have too many threads allocated to that cgroup, if the threads are experiencing excessive competition for the available cores.

How can I do that?

Without cgropups, I'd simply use load average in `top` with the rule of thumb that load average should be less than the number of cores. Is there something similart that takes cgroup/cpuset into account?

Comment: If you have cgroups integrated with systemd, you can use systemd-cgtop

Comment: @RamanSailopal Not available on my machine (RHEL 6), and I am not even an admin. Thank you for the suggestion, though, it may work in more modern environment

Comment: It is possible to list processes with ps with information about their cgroups. Then filter only those with "R" state (running), and appropriate cgroup you are interested in, and finally count them.  I was not able to use pgrep to filter by cgroup.
This may be changing rapidly, though, so probably some average would be needed over a few gathered samples.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you care about, there are two options:

#### If you care about how many threads/processes are in the cgroup, but not the 'load average':

Simply count the lines in the `tasks` file for the cgroup.  This file will automatically update whenever a thread or process is created or removed in the cgroup.

#### If you care about actual utilization:

This is a bit trickier.  You can get a list of processes/threads in the cgroup from the above mentioned `tasks` file, and then check usage for each PID using `/proc`, but that approach has so many race conditions you could monetize it as a competitive sport.  Alternatively, if you're using version 2 cgroups, you can check the `cpu.stat` file in the cgroup.  This file will have a couple of lines counting microseconds of CPU time consumed by the cgroup, so you can get a rough estimate of usage by checking it two times one second apart and dividing the difference by 10000 to get a utilization percentage (100% for full utilization of one core, 20% for full utilization of two, etc).  A similar approach can be done with version one cgroups with the cpuacct controller (create a cgroup under that controller mirroring the one you created under the cpuset controller).

Comment: Your algorithm of checking usage will show values only up to cpu limit defined by a cgroup, wouldn't it? cgroup will not use more cpu than it is allowed, so this is far from "load average" metric, or I miss something?

Comment: @Kuchara You’re correct that it’s not really load average, but it does track CPU utilization relative to system-wide capabilities (as opposed to just within the constraints of the cgroup) because `cpu.stat` (and the cpuacct equivalent) track actual execution time and the formula does not factor in any limits on the cgroup itself. My math was off though in the original answer (it should be divide by 10000, not by 10, I must have been thinking in terms of milliseconds instead of microseconds for some reason that day).

Comment: I mean that when there is a limit set on cgroup, utilization calculated by your formula will show only up to the limit set on cgroup. (e.g. if cgroup limits usage to 300% of cpu), you should get only up to 300%, right? It is still useful, though. When the usage is steady on the limit, one can see something may be off.

Comment: @Kuchara Correct, it won’t ever show anything over the limit, but that is (arguably) an accurate representation of the cgroup’s resource utilization.

Answer (score 0):

I have written simple script to calculate a load average for a cgroup this process is executed in.

```
$ cat loadavg-cgroup.sh
#!/bin/bash

sample_time=${1:-1} # in seconds
sample_count=${2:-10}
sleep_time="$(echo "scale=2 ; ${sample_time}/${sample_count}" | bc)"

cgroup=$(grep '^2:cpu:' /proc/$$/cgroup)
export cgroup

{
        for _ in $(seq 1 "${sample_count}" ) ; do
                # note, for cgroup v2 use newest pgrep
                ps -eLo cgroup,stat | grep "${cgroup}" | grep ' R[l+]*$' --count
                sleep "${sleep_time}"
        done
} \
| awk '{ sum+=$1 } END { print (sum/NR) - 1 } '
```

Usage:

```
# To calculate load average for period of 10 seconds
$ ./loadavg-cgroup.sh 10
1.6
```

Remarks:

- sampling time and no. of samples is parameterized (as first and second parameters, respectively)
- this is for cgroups v1, as I had this on hand in my WSL2 env
- newest `pgrep` would work with seraching cgroups as well, so it would be better to use it than ps+grep+grep trio.
- does not include `ps` in load average
- this will not work for cases when a process is not in a cgroup, but adapting it should be failrly simple